# Rust: Can a generic parameter have bounds referencing other parameters?

Tags: generics, rust

I want to create a function that takes two arrays of comparable types and compares them lexicographically, like so

```
use std::cmp::Eq;

fn compare_arrays<T : Eq<U>, U>(a1: &[T], a2: &[U]) -> bool {
    //Comparison code here
    return false
}
```

However, the Rust compiler does not accept `T : Eq<U>`. Is there some other syntax to do this, so that I can indicate comparability of `T` and `U` in the function signature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, type constraints can use other type parameters. The error you're seeing is because [`Eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.Eq.html) *is not generic*.

```
error[E0107]: wrong number of type arguments: expected 0, found 1
 --> src/lib.rs:3:26
  |
3 | fn compare_arrays<T : Eq<U>, U>(a1: &[T], a2: &[U]) -> bool {
  |                          ^ unexpected type argument
```

Use [`PartialEq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/cmp/trait.PartialEq.html) instead.